# Chose name for first publication (special characters and compound names)

Tags: authorship, personal-name, international

I am submitting my first paper ever in a couple of months and I was wondering about my family name. The paper is in English and the conference is an international conference.

Assume my name is {Alan} {võn Neumann} {Chúrch}, so {first name} {family name father} and {family name mother} where {**family name father has two words**}. Note also the special characters (õ and ú) I added there on purpose (as I do have them in my real name).

If I had the choice, I would go with  {Alan} {võn Neumann} {Chúrch}, but I don't want to be cited as Chúrch or Võn. A proper citation would be võn Neumann Chúrch, but võn Neumann would be fine as well.

How can I ensure that I would be properly cited? 
Also, should I keep the special characters? I really would rather keep them.

Best,
Not Alan von Neumann Church ;)

Comment: Have you considered using a pseudonym?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

+1 for thinking about this *before* your first publication. Have you read through the other questions tagged [personal-name](/questions/tagged/personal-name)? They may be helpful.

In your case, I’d go with *Alan võn Neumann,* or *võn Neumann, Alan* if your target journal uses this format.

If you include *Chúrch,* then I’ll *guarantee* that you will start being referenced as “Chúrch (2015)” - maybe not on this publication, but later. (You *do* plan on using a consistent name throughout your sciencific career, right?) Bibliographic databases may be smart enough to pick this up, but they will need to rely on journal editors including your correct name in their journal databases, and this is where noise will creep in.

Conversely, I wouldn’t worry too much about the diacritical characters, as long as their mapping to basic characters is straightforward. Search engines understand this, so it won’t make a difference whether your name is listed as *võn Neumann* or *von Neumann.* One exception would be [German *ß*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F), where it is not obvious that this should be transcribed *ss.* IIRC, people have legally changed their names over this.

Comment: +1 for the nice answer and, especially, for mentioning of being _consistent_ - an important point that I missed to note in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, yes I saw three other answers that were related to the problem (including changing maiden names etc) but none about having two family names.
I also think they will mess up the two family names indeed... I'll probably go for the Alan võn Neumann I guess, to be pragmatic...
Thanks again!
And yes, of course I plan on being consistent! :)

Comment: To add to the last point: The biggest problem with the *ß* is if the author’s list of a paper is given in all-caps or small caps, in which case it usually is converted to *SS* (and it will take some time for the [capital ß](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_ẞ) to be established). It is impossible for the reader to say from this whether, e.g., somebody whose name is given as *MUSSMANN* is actually named *Mußmann* or *Mussmann* – even native speakers of German won’t be able to do this.

Comment: In another note, while I agree with you that somebody will get the compound surname wrong, the likelihood of this is somewhat lower than with a normal double surname thanks to the surname prefix *võn:* When I read something like *Alan võn Neumann Chúrch,* I can be pretty certain that a surname starts at *võn.* With *Alan Neumann Chúrch,* it is more difficult to tell whether *Neumann* is part of the surname or a middle name.

Comment: Actually, thats an interesting point. When I submit a paper its anonymous, if they do accpet it, I have to send the camera ready version. At what point do I tell them what my name is? Or do they usually take it from the camera ready version and they are suposed to be smart enough to figure it out? Because I know someone with the case "Alan Church vonNeuman" and he got "von Neumann'ed", but as you say my case could posibly "save itself" lol

Comment: @excalibur1491: Usually, right upon the initial submission. The *paper* is anonymous (i.e. does not contain your name and affiliation) toward the *reviewers*, but all of that metadata usually has to be entered during the initial submission in forms in the submission system and editors can access it all the time.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: I agree with your assessment concerning *võn*, however capitalization plays into this, and in styles that fully capitalize the surname (which is rare in the paper styleguides I am familiar with, but, in other contexts such as names in e-mails/letters, at least seems to be reasonably commonplace in French and sometimes also Spanish), it might once again be tricky to tell whether *VÕN NEUMANN* is the prefixed name "võn Neumann", or a name composed of two individual names, "Võn" and "Neumann".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, double-blind review is really only common in Computer Science. It's much less common in other fields.

Comment: @BillBarth: double-blind review is the norm in psychology, and I am just revising an OR paper that was double-blinded. But we may be getting off topic here...

Comment: @BillBarth: As the OP wrote "When I submit a paper its anonymous", I took it for granted that they *are* subject to double-blind review.

Comment: Having the mother's surname as second surname is a South American thing. It will get people confused. 
In most countries the father's surname is used (where there's equality you can choose the mother's too), in some you can have your kids get both surnames with a dash in the middle (it's still one surname), but I think it's still dangerous as it's not a standard. 
The father's surname is used as default in the whole world, and it's the one that comes first in your name and would probably get assigned to you in foreign countries if you had to choose only one.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper As you can imagine from the fake name I chose in this post, I am indeed in the CS field and the submission is double-blinded. (The conference is AAAI, if that gives you more info, but I guess I'll submit to other in my life hehe)

Comment: @Formagella: More precisely, having two surnames, one from each parent, is customary wherever Spanish or Portuguese are spoken, not just in South America.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, Hi again. Today I was reviewing my paper and found that BibTex does tricky things with diacritical characters as one of my citations was missing a letter with a diacriticala ccent because in the original bibtex from the editor they used the leter like è instead of \\`{e}. Is it possibel to force editors to automatically do this when submitting your paper? Thanks again

Comment: @excalibur1491: yes, that's something I often struggle with, too. Possibly the problem is not with BibTeX but with your main document. Try including an encoding that would allow you to use these diacritics in your main document. (Or, in the interest of maximum foolproofness, search-replace with \'{} in your .bib file.) Otherwise, look through [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to write your pen name with a dash: võn Neumann-Chúrch. This could be a reasonable compromise: On the one hand, you can keep both of your actual surnames. On the other hand, the risk of being misquoted is slightly greater than if you drop the second surname (but it is smaller than if you keep both and write them without a dash).

Comment: I can confirm that a dash-version would work (i.e. is recognized and cited correctly by automatic programs). Surnames with dashes are quite common at least in some contries.

Comment: @jofel Yes, they are common in certain countries where you can chose to have a double surname (with dash) after marriage.

Comment: I'm not someone (or from a country) with father/mother names - so I don't know if that would be a bastardisation or not - but to me that appears as though "von" applies to both, not "von Neumann"-"Church". Whether that matters or not I presume depends on whether it offends (or just seems wrong to) someone with that form of name.

Comment: Won't someone think there are two authors, instead? Like, you know, Gay-Lussac, Boyle-Mariotte or similar.

Comment: @Lohoris unlikely, since these would be separated either by a slash (/) or a comma on a paper. (if you are lucky enough to have a law or conjecture etc. named after you, well than you are probably famous enough not to care about the correct citation of your name,)

Comment: @Lohoris Sometimes, to avoid confusion, a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) is used to separate two names of the same author while an [en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash) is used to separate the names of two people. This subtlety has become particularly well known in number theory, because of a famous open problem called the [Birch–Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture) (that's two people, not three).

Comment: I use such a compound, hypen-separated surname myself and I've always been cited correctly. As an added benefit, the resulting surname is so rare it makes it extremely easy to find my publications.

Answer (score 3):

Despite Stephan's comments on diacritical characters, I would still worry somehow about them. I do not know what the state of the art is today, but I saw in horror once an article of mine being from **Mylast*error*ame** instead of **Mylastname**, with **n** being a diacritical character.

And yes, Google still finds the wrong version.

I do not care about that anymore (having left the academics world) but, should I have known, I would have dropped anything which is not ASCII in my name immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my opinion on the topic. Firstly, a proper citation for a paper is more of a function of a particular *publishing style* (APA, Chicago, etc.) than your naming preferences. Secondly, while I can totally understand your desire to keep the original alphabet's letters with [diacritical marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic), I see a potential problem with that. What I mean is that citations, including such letters, for some people (audience), might be difficult to *reproduce (cite)*, *search for* and (for authors) get proper *attribution*.

Therefore, I guess, this problem requires making a trade-off between desiring to present information most *accurately* in terms of *naming* and more pragmatic aspects (*convenience* for authors and their audience as well as better accuracy in terms of *attribution*).

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr. What is your opinion in the compound names then (2 family names)?
As for the diacritical marks, I am not so much concerned, I have come accross papers from Brazilans, Spaniards etc. Google Scholar finds those authors with no problem (you can try names as Gómez, Núñez, García, etc, they all work well)

Comment: @excalibur1491: You're welcome. In regard to compound names, I think that the best advice is to choose one arrangement and use it _consistently_, as mentioned by Stephan. As for diacritical marks, I would be more careful. My point was not concerned about their handling by Google Scholar and similar systems, but rather potential problems due to people's inability (non- or differently-internationalized keyboards) or impatience for typing those letters as well as potential for accidental omission of citations in a search because of letter similarity in appearance (i.e., García vs. Garcia).

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh If people don't cite names with diacritical marks correctly then that reflects badly on the person doing the citation. Why should someone mangle their own name to allow others not to use symbols.... heck, a copy and paste would do. - Search engines are generally fine with those not being in the search term.
(I've seen a few papers with names that have diacritical marks and if they are a part of the name they should be printed.)

Comment: @DetlevCM: I agree with you. However, when rightly blaming someone, who cited a paper inaccurately, you're missing my point that, in such scenario, e-repositories and/or citation indices might fail to provide the authors proper (or any) attribution, thus, negatively affecting both parties.

Comment: @excalibur1491: Pah, Brazilians, Spaniards, ... [Latvian names](http://search.proquest.com/openview/0923d819fda4773adbcd13efe01adde0/1?pq-origsite=gscholar) is where things get interesting ;)

Comment: A search for "von Neumann Church" or "Garcia" will almost always now match "võn Neumann Chúrch" or "García". This is part of the Unicode standard, and all big search engines will comply. This might have been an issue some years ago, but I don't think it will be now.

Comment: @MJeffryes: I'm assuming that your comment is targeting me. I'm sure that you're correct about major search engines. However, I'm pretty sure that e-repositories, citation indices and other services, such as ResearcherID and ORCID, are not that smart at the moment, which potentially might result in serious authors attribution issues.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Right, you can't be *certain* it won't cause issues (although at least for ORCID you can list multiple names, eg with and without accents), so it depends how much value you put in having your name correctly rendered.

Comment: @MJeffryes: I agree - it's a balancing act (trade-off).

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh In that case I'd extend the blame to the repository as having and "too narrow English mindset" focussed around only the characters found in the English language. Given how international science is, it would seem fairly obvious that support should exist for all kinds of diacritical marks - including the algorithms to identify common misspellings.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: Attribution issues? I'm afraid I don't understand the use case. **Either**, I know of a paper, but I don't know who wrote it. In that case, I will have some identifying information, such as title, year, and/or DOI. I can enter that information in some digital library, and I will get to the paper and thus find out who wrote it - but in this case, it is irrelevant whether or not the digital library supports soft matching of Unicode characters. **Or**, I already know the name of the author. However, in that case, attribution is already clear, I don't need the digital library ...

Comment: ... to determine it. Hence, where is the **attribution issue**? On the contrary, I rather see an attribution issue caused by normalizing to ASCII, given that this means some people whose name is **García** end up being written the same as other people whose name is **Garcia**, and thus are easier to confuse.

Comment: @DetlevCM: My point is concerned not about who to extend the **blame** to, but, rather, assessing whether there is a **risk** of negative side effects and what parties are prone to that risk. Blaming repositories wouldn't help authors with dealing with the fact of losing attribution for their work.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Re: understanding the use case. You write: "I can enter that information in some digital library...", which really means "I can **search** information in some digital library". That's the point: you don't enter the information, but, rather search - it is someone else, who entered that information earlier; and, if that information is entered incorrectly or not accurately, you simply _will not be able to find_ that paper in that digital library, which I refer to above as e-repository, hence the _attribution_ problem. The ASCII-related issue is just another potential related problem.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: "you simply will not be able to find that paper" - yes, I will, as I am searching by DOI, or by paper title, or something else, if I want to *find out author names*. As I said, if I *already know author names*, attribution is already clear, hence I do not need to search for them.

Comment: I am honestly not too concerned about the diacritical characters. I'm in the computer science field and pretty much all goes through Google Scholar and it finds perfectly, as a matter of fact I happen to cite two brazilian papers where names have ão at the end, and had no problem (even University of São Paolo has it..). Also, my family name is that uncommon that I doubt it will ever be atributed to another person (garcia and garcía could happen, but I guarantee mine wouldn't, no one that I found on Google Scholar has my family name).

Comment: But thank all of you for your comments, I obviously take them into account and I'll end up deciding something when I submit in a couple months based on your advice :)