# Should I write my name with accents in my article?

Tags: publications, personal-name, international

My first name is pretty common, but in Spanish it is accentuated.

I've seen people keeping their names accented and people who don't. I wonder if there's a formal recommendation on this matter.

Comment: Also relevant: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46942/7734

Comment: If you prefer the way your name looks with its accent, go for it (I would!), but understand that not everyone will write it the same way, since not everyone has figured out how to produce accents with their keyboard.